# Unexpected behavious of SharePoint Regional Site Settings

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I want to set date format as MM/dd/YYYY (05/31/2016) for my SharePoint site collection. To do the date format settings I have updated Locale settings in Regional Settings from Site Settings -> Regional Settings under Site Administration. I have updated Locale as "English (Caribbean)" which sets date format as MM/dd/yyyy (05/31/2016). It works in my development environment. When I have updated same settings on QA server and set Locale as "English (Caribbean)" it shows date format as dd/MM/YYYY (31/05/2016).

I have also tried to get Date using PowerShell with Locale "English (Caribbean)" via PowerShell on QA server however it also display date in dd/MM/YYYY format. My client needs date in format of MM/dd/YYYY (05/31/2016).

Is there anyone who face same issue in his career and resolve it. Any kind of help is much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure Regional Settings are set to English on you Internet Browser

Comment: All the settings on my DEV server and QA Server are same which is listed as below:

Timezone: (UTC -05:00) Eastern Time (US and Canada)
Locale: English (Caribbean)
Sort Order: General
Calendar: Gregorian
Alternate Calendar: None
Time Format: 12 Hour